# scrambling GBT data to identify counterpart

Tags: vhdl, fpga, system-verilog, digital-logic

this question is FPGA-design-and-languages agnostic. I use bidirectional gigabit optical transmission lines (GBT) for communication of two distant counterparts. The GBT frame payload is 80 bits, out of them I use 64, so I have additional 16 bits for spare usage.

The master sends consecutively each 25ns a packet of 80 bits, and the same works the other way around. I need to assure, that master sends the data to a client, which has specific firmware implemented, so during the communication I need to identify, that client is equipped with a firmware version required to digest the data I'm sending. The communication is not transaction based, but the optical link rather realizes 80bit register to 80bit register seamless pass-through. Unfortunately the 16 spare bits I have to my disposition I just cannot simply set to a constant value, and somehow code into that constant the target firmware. Such method is quite common, and I could not guarantee 100% firmwares match.

I was thinking whether there would exist some sort of symmetric data scrambling, which could be used to send from slave to master over such scrambled channel the constants needed. I was wondering if there exist some 'standard' solution how to identify two counterparts in a hardware communication channel by some reasonably simple means in terms of required logic elements.

I do not want to encrypt the data. I just want to assure that the firmwares match.

What is the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply barrel-rotate your data by one bit. This would result in essentially a ceasar cipher - not cryptographically secure, but noone is going to accidentally implement the same thing in a different firmware. Also, it gives you the ability to differentiate between 79 different firmware versions(shift one bit, two bits, three ...).

However, this seems overly complicated to me. I can't think of a time when either transmitting a version code in the 16 spare bits or exchanging version numbers at the beginning of communication in a handshake-style patten wouldn't make more sense.